# XQuery - calculating number of elements

Tags: function, recursion, tree, xquery

I'm trying to declare a user-defined function in XQuery, that would be passed an element and would return the total number of elements in its tree (meaning itself plus its subtree).

Is this even possible to do in XQuery with a recursive function or will I need another approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. As this has a smell of homework, I'm not giving a full answer, but the idea on how to do it.

For both cases, you'll have to consider *which* children to consider while counting. Reading your question, it looks like you're looking for elements only and can safely ignore attributes, comments, text nodes and processing instructions.

#### Using a Recursive Function

Define a function, which sums up the size of each individual subtree (which you determine by a recursive function call). Something like (this is not XQuery code!):

```
function subtree_size {
  sum(
    for each element
    return subtree_size(current element)
  )
}
```

#### Passing all Elements to the `count` Function

XQuery has a `count` function, which returns the number of elements passed. There is a very short and rather easy to find XPath expression to return all descendant nodes (including the node itself). Have a look at the axis steps available in XPath.

Comment: Great, that is something I can build upon :-) . My main problem was with summation.